# See network requests spike but nginx log shows nothing special

Tags: amazon-web-services

So it is not http requests that's bombarding our server it seems.

Which log should I look at in order to know what kind of requests the host is receiving?

I'm attaching the monitoring info of the ec2 instance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VPC Flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) are the best way to diagnose this type of network issue in AWS.

They will give you metadata about each flow in your VPC. They don't log packet contents, just that a flow happened. This will let you see the source, destination, port, and protocol of the request, and there will be a matching entry about the response. They're not the easiest things to understand, but maybe there's tools to help with that.

Remember to set a retention period on your CloudWatch Logs stream that holds the VPC flow logs, as a busy VPC can quickly create a lot of data, increasing storage costs. Also, turn the VPC flow logs off if you don't need them on.